# How can I get python to recognize the xlsx files?

Tags: python

I have a problem with a `xlsx`. `Pycharm` does not recognize it or that is the impression it gives me in [heres for the details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX8Gv.png) .

**Code**

```
import openpyxl
openpyxl.load_workbook(inventory.xlsx)
```

Comment: needs to be a `str` input 'file.xlsx'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution was similar as previously answered: **Settings / Preferences | Editor | File Types**. But then the pattern was found in Auto-detect file type by content. I removed the incorrect file name pattern and everything now works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
path = "yourpath"
openpyxl.load_workbook(path + "inventory.xlsx")
```